# Lightgbm inside docker libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, docker-compose, lightgbm

I have LightGBM installed in my mac and tested earlier for a different project.

Now I am inside a docker with python 3.6 on my mac. As soon as I add `import lightgbm as lgbm` in my Flask application, I get error

```
OSError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is going on? Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: Do you able to resolve this issue? Can you post the solution?

Comment: Yes, I basically forgot to include `libgomp` in my installation list inside docker

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me, include it in your dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y install curl
RUN apt-get install libgomp1
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2223#issuecomment-499788066

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the image yo use you may need a c++ compiler, together with `libgomp1` too. The issue is that Lightgbm is coded in c++ indeed and the base image of your dockerfile may not have all dependencies installed by default (while your mac has).

Following these links

( https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/master/docker/dockerfile-cli)
(https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/2223)

the solution would be to add to the dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        cmake \
        build-essential \
        gcc \
        g++ \
        git && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get install libgomp1 -y
```