# Azureml Training model fail with libgomp.so.1

Tags: python-3.x, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-machine-learning-service, mlops, azuremlsdk

I hope you can help me out with this issue as I cannot figure out what is wrong or how to solve it.
I am diving into MLOps to have a better understanding of the workflow and process. I found an open source project to test my knowledge(I am not sure if I can share a GitHub link here of the project.

I started with creating the infra (workspace, storage account, KeyVault and container registry and a cluster).

Once that has been done, I create the following pipeline:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - machine-learning-pipelines
pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  displayName: 'Use Python 3.7'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 3.7

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Install Python Requirements'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: './package_requirement/install_requirements.sh'
    workingDirectory: 'package_requirement'

- bash: |
   pytest training/train_test.py --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --cov=data_test --cov-report=xml --cov-report=html
   
  displayName: 'Data Test'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  displayName: 'Publish Test Results **/test-*.xml'
  inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/test-*.xml'
  condition: succeededOrFailed()

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Install Azure ml CLI'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<service-principle>'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az extension add -n azure-cli-ml'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'create Azure ML workspace'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<service-principle>'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az ml workspace create -g <resource-group> -w <workspace> -l westeurope --exist-ok --yes'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<service-principle>'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az ml computetarget create amlcompute -g <resource-group> -w <workspace> -n amlhricluster -s STANDARD_DS2_V2 --min-nodes 0 --max-nodes 2 --idle-seconds-before-scaledown 300'

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Upload Data to Datastore'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<service-principle>'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az ml datastore upload -w <workspace> -g <resource-group> -n $(az ml datastore show-default -w <workspace> -g <resource-group> --query name -o tsv) -p data -u insurance --overwrite true'

- bash: 'mkdir metadata && mkdir models'
  displayName: 'Make Metadata and Models Directory'


- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Training Model'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<service-principle>'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az ml run submit-script -g <resource-group> -w <workspace> -e insurance_classification --ct amlhricluster -d conda_dependencies.yml -c train_insurance -t ../metadata/run.json train_aml.py'
    workingDirectory: training

- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Registering Model'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<service-principle>'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az ml model register -g <resource-group> -w <workspace> -n insurance_model -f metadata/run.json --asset-path outputs/models/insurance_model.pkl -d "Classification model for filling a claim prediction" --tag "data"="insurance" --tag "model"="classification" --model-framework ScikitLearn -t metadata/model.json'

- task: AzureCli@2
  displayName: 'Downloading Model'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<service-principle>'
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az ml model download -g <resource-group> -w <workspace> -i $(jq -r .modelId metadata/model.json) -t ./models --overwrite'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: |
     **/metadata/*
     **/models/*
     **/deployment/*
     **/tests/integration/*
     **/package_requirement/*
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: 'Publish Pipeline Artifact'
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: Landing
```

My `train_insurance.runconfig` looks like this

```
framework: Python
communicator: None
autoPrepareEnvironment: true
maxRunDurationSeconds:
nodeCount: 1
environment:
  name: project_environment
  python:
    userManagedDependencies: false
    interpreterPath: python
    condaDependenciesFile: conda_dependencies.yml
    baseCondaEnvironment:
  docker:
    enabled: true
    baseImage: mcr.microsoft.com/azureml/o16n-sample-user-base/ubuntu-miniconda
    sharedVolumes: true
    gpuSupport: false
    shmSize: 1g
    arguments: []
history:
  outputCollection: true
  snapshotProject: true
  directoriesToWatch:
  - logs
dataReferences:
  workspaceblobstore:
    dataStoreName: workspaceblobstore
    pathOnDataStore: insurance
    mode: download
    overwrite: true
    pathOnCompute:
```

and my `conda_dependencies.yaml` is this:

```
# Conda environment specification. The dependencies defined in this file will
# be automatically provisioned for managed runs. These include runs against
# the localdocker, remotedocker, and cluster compute targets.

# Note that this file is NOT used to automatically manage dependencies for the
# local compute target. To provision these dependencies locally, run:
# conda env update --file conda_dependencies.yml

# Details about the Conda environment file format:
# https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#create-environment-file-by-hand

# For managing Spark packages and configuration, see spark_dependencies.yml.
# Version of this configuration file's structure and semantics in AzureML.
# This directive is stored in a comment to preserve the Conda file structure.
# [AzureMlVersion] = 2

name: amlproj06_training_env
dependencies:
  # The python interpreter version.
  # Currently Azure ML Workbench only supports 3.5.2 and later.
  - python=3.7.*
  - pip=20.2.4

  - pip:
      - urllib3_1_26_2
      - azureml
      - azure-cli
      - Cython
      - gcc7
      # Base AzureML SDK
      - azureml-sdk

      # Must match AzureML SDK version.
      # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-environments
      - azureml-defaults
      - azureml-core
      # Training deps
      - scikit-learn
      - numpy
      - pytest
      - pytest-cov
      # Scoring deps
      - inference-schema[numpy-support]

      # MLOps with R
      - azure-storage-blob

      # LightGBM bosting lib
      - lightgbm

      # lightgbm Caps because we are throwing darts
      - LightGBM

      # Job lib- whatever I don't know what we use it for
      - joblib

      # Install Pandas
      - pandas
```

and my `install_requirements.sh` is this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libgomp1
python --version
pip install --upgrade azure-cli
pip install --upgrade azureml-sdk
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip freeze
```

But at the task `Training Model`, everything seems to be going well, until this error shows up, and the task fails:

```
WARNING: Auto upgrade failed. name 'exit_code' is not defined
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3892253Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3895010Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 697, in _run_job
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3896066Z     result = cmd_copy(params)
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3897247Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/__init__.py", line 333, in __call__
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3898550Z     return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3900098Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/command_operation.py", line 121, in handler
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3901165Z     return op(**command_args)
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3902335Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azureml/_cli/cli_command.py", line 305, in command_wrapper
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3903290Z     retval = function(*args, **kwargs)
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3904464Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azureml/_cli/run/run_commands.py", line 542, in submit_run
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3905481Z     run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True, wait_post_processing=True)
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3906746Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azureml/core/run.py", line 846, in wait_for_completion
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3907678Z     raise_on_error=raise_on_error)
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3908827Z   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.13/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/azureml/core/run.py", line 1096, in _stream_run_output
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3909824Z     raise ActivityFailedException(error_details=json.dumps(error, indent=4))
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3910729Z azureml.exceptions._azureml_exception.ActivityFailedException: ActivityFailedException:
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3911536Z    Message: Activity Failed:
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3912179Z {
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3912780Z     "error": {
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3913417Z         "code": "UserError",
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3914262Z         "message": "User program failed with OSError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3915114Z         "messageParameters": {},
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3916068Z         "detailsUri": "https://aka.ms/azureml-run-troubleshooting",
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3917645Z         "details": []
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3918315Z     },
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3919200Z     "time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3919847Z }
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3920390Z    InnerException None
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3920963Z    ErrorResponse 
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3921493Z {
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3922011Z     "error": {
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3923684Z         "message": "Activity Failed:\n{\n    \"error\": {\n        \"code\": \"UserError\",\n        \"message\": \"User program failed with OSError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\",\n        \"messageParameters\": {},\n        \"detailsUri\": \"https://aka.ms/azureml-run-troubleshooting\",\n        \"details\": []\n    },\n    \"time\": \"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z\"\n}"
2022-07-21T10:12:17.3925244Z     }
```

the WARNING happens during the docker image pull.
Regarding the libgomp I did installed it in my ubuntu agent, but it keeps showing the error.

Please did anyone ever faced this issue and know a workaround?

If you need more info please do not hesitate to ask and I will provide.

Comment: [ImportError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764624/importerror-libgomp-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-direc), [Lightgbm inside docker libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55036740/lightgbm-inside-docker-libgomp-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file) and [OSError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/463704/oserror-libgompso1-cannot-open-shared-object-file.html)

Answer (score 0):

**libgomp.so.1** is causing the error. When **xgboost** is trying to load the library in **runtime**. When it failed, it will throw this kind of error.  But the container image “**`mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python`**” does not have such library for function apps in azure based on python.

Instead of “**libgomp.so.1**” load the libraries `libglib-2.0.so.0` and `libgthread-2.0.so.0` in runtime and re-run the container.

We need to install libglib-2.0.so.0 on Ubuntu machine.

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386 libXrender1:i386 libsm6:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386
```

**This is for Ubuntu version greater than 14.04**