# Lightgbm/Streamlit with docker - OSError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, streamlit, lightgbm

I am using streamlit and lightgbm with docker and I am currently getting this error.

```
OSError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
  File "/src/stream.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightgbm/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .basic import Booster, Dataset, Sequence, register_logger
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 110, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 101, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
```

I tried updating my Dockerfile to include libgomp1 alongside the other dependencies listed in this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73140670/14651739

My dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /src/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        cmake \
        build-essential \
        gcc \
        g++ \
        git && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install curl

RUN apt-get install libgomp1 -y
    # apt-get install curl 

FROM python:3.10.0-slim-buster

WORKDIR /src

COPY requirements.txt /src/

COPY --from=0 /src ./
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501

COPY . /src/
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]
CMD [ "stream.py" ]
```

My requirements.txt file

```
pandas
sklearn
streamlit
lightgbm
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using multi-stage builds so you need to install libgomp1 also in the runtime stage. Here's a modified Dockerfile that installs libgomp1 once more in the second stage.

```
# build stage
FROM ubuntu:latest as builder
WORKDIR /src/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils \
    ca-certificates \
    cmake \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    git \
    curl \
    libgomp1 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# runtime stage
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

# install libgomp1 agagin
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libgomp1 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /src

COPY --from=builder /src/requirements.txt /src/
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8501

COPY --from=builder /src /src/
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]
CMD ["stream.py"]
```

Also note the remark from lightgdm [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/python-package#install-from-pypi):

> For Linux users, glibc >= 2.14 is required for LightGBM <=3.3.3 and glibc >= 2.28 is required for newer versions. Also, in some rare cases, when you hit OSError: libgomp.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory error during importing LightGBM, you need to install OpenMP runtime library separately (use your package manager and search for lib[g|i]omp for doing this).

so I recommend you to properly pin your dependencies.